# Mismatched #if/#endif and "preprocessor command must start as first nonwhite space"

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#ifndef PP_H
#define PP_H

class Pball
{
public:
    Pball(int r, int c);
    bool func1(int r, int c);
    void func2() const;
private:
    int r;
    int c;
};
#endif
```

I can't seem to find where these errors C2014 and C1070 are coming from. As far as I can tell, the syntax is correct. There must be something wrong elsewhere. Any help?

Update, here are the error logs:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C1070   mismatched #if/#endif pair in file (...my directory)

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2014   preprocessor command must start as first nonwhite space

Comment: Perhaps the file encoding is corrupted?

Comment: The code is correct. Post the full error message.

Comment: Maybe there's a BOM sign added that compiler cannot parse?

Comment: @zdf I updated the post with the error log.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a problem with visual studios not catching up to my code. Restarted and all issues were gone ¯_(ツ)_/¯